# City Radius and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form where people can select a city and radius (up to 500mi) and then i would get all the zip codes for those cities within 500mi (Radius).

Then i would query mySQL so -> http://pastie.org/1670269

Is there a better way to do this ? Because sometimes it takes 2 minutes to query.

Regards

Comment: Are you properly indexing your table? How many rows are in the shipments table? Look at MySQL's `EXPLAIN` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) and run some profiling to see why it's taking so long.  I use Navicat and there is a "Profiling" tab when you run queries that breaks down all the timing.

Comment: Depends where you're getting your list of zip code from. If it's another table in your database, then you can use a SQL join rather than a long list in an IN clause

Comment: Even if you don't have it in a table, it might be better to create a table and put them in there!

Comment: on the Table JOIN part... how do you join if you have 100s of zip codes.. the Radius is calculated by PHP and then zip codes are extracted for each one... i can not just do table1.zipcode = table2.zipcode i would still need 100s of ORs right

Answer (score 1):

Try geospatial queries: http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

It might also be worth looking into using mongo db (if possible), as it does geospatial stuff quite well (and much faster than MySQL): http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing